# Installing Octave: Bad Interpreter: No Such File or Directory

Tags: octave, homebrew

I'm trying to install Octave according to the instructions here:

```
http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_MacOS_X
```

using Homebrew.

I have the XCode command line tools installed.  I checked and I also have HomeBrew installed.  I just installed XQuartz.

I try to run brew tap homebrew/science, and I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 26: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0
```

Do I need to do this in a certain folder?

Not sure why I'm getting this issue.

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Comment: what does `brew doctor` say.  it looks like you've installed homebrew then maybe upgraded your system perhaps? (so the ruby version it got installed under no longer exists). I would try reinstall homebrew...

Comment: @Doon Hmm, I run "brew doctor" and get /usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 26: /usr/local/Library/brew.rb: Undefined error: 0       Seems like I can't run any brew commands :(

Comment: so I think the second part of my comment is correct, you installed brew, then upgraded and the ruby version isn't there anymore.. I would just do a clean install of homebrew.  and you should be set.

Comment: @Doon OK, so homebrew's site says to run "rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup" but I don't think it likes the "brew cleanup" part (gives me same error as before)...

Comment: yeah your brew is pretty much borked,   the cleanup isn't going to work. but once you removed Cellar and .git, you should be able to just reinstall brew in the same location